# How can I turn off Num Lock in Windows 7 and 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I'm teaching a couple of people how to use the NVDA screenreader, which requires that Num Lock is turned off. I'm having trouble getting Num Lock to automatically turn off when the computer starts up, however.

I've tried setting Num Lock to off in the BIOS, but this doesn't seem to work (although it does seem to switch Num Lock off until Windows boots); I've also tried tweaking the registry, but this doesn't seem to work either:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000792.htm

When I restart the computer, it seems to forget the registry setting.

What should I try next to get Num Lock to automatically turn off when the computer starts?

Comment: search the registery for `InitialKeyboardIndicators`, and set it to 0 everywhere it occurs (it will occur in a number of places, not just HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard as your article indicates). I've never been able to determine a rhyme or reason to why one one key changes it and the others are ignored, so you just have to change them all. Also, change it even if the current value is not 0-3 (usually its 2147483648 or -2147483648 to indicate an invalid value). And note, on Win8, you must be using local accounts, not your hotmail.

Comment: Thank you, Frank; I won't be seeing the client until next week but will try then and report back.